# Text Section is not delayed in the JavaScript by using IntersectionObserver and SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, dom

`

```
<section class="featured-section">
        <div class="feature-container">
          <div class="container-div-1">
            <div class="container-1">
              <p class="container-description">
                200<span class="container-style-1">+</span>
              </p>
              <p class="container-description-1">Companies helped</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-div-2">
            <div class="container-2">
              <p class="container-description">
                150<span class="container-style-1">m</span>
              </p>
              <p class="container-description-2">Revenue generated</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container-div-3">
            <div class="container-3">
              <p class="container-description">
                700<span class="container-style-3">+</span>
              </p>
              <p class="container-description-3">Sucessful projects</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`
```

This is my code Structure of Html
JavaScript Code

```
`const featureSection = document.querySelector(".featured-section");

if (featureSection) {
  const containerDivs = featureSection.querySelectorAll(".feature-container");

  const revealSection = function (entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach((entry, index) => {
      if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;

      const textElements = [
        ...entry.target.querySelectorAll(".container-description"),
        ...entry.target.querySelectorAll(".container-description-1"),
        ...entry.target.querySelectorAll(".container-description-2"),
        ...entry.target.querySelectorAll(".container-description-3"),
      ];

      textElements.forEach((textElement, textIndex) => {
        textElement.style.animation = "fadeIn 1s ease-in-out";
        setTimeout(() => {
          textElement.style.opacity = "1";
          textElement.style.transform = "none";
        }, index * 1000);
        // Delay each text element by 1000 milliseconds multiplied by its index
      });

      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    });
  };

  const sectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(revealSection, {
    root: null,
    threshold: 0.15,
  });

  containerDivs.forEach((containerDiv, index) => {
    containerDiv.style.animation = "fadeIn 1s ease-in-out";
    containerDiv.style.transitionDelay = `${index * 1000}ms`;
    // Delay each container div by 3000ms multiplied by its index
    sectionObserver.observe(containerDiv);
  });
}
```

` This is my code structure of html and JavaScript I wanna delay the display of text content for example I first wanna load the first part of the div and then 2nd and then 3rd with 1000ms delay but this code is not working for me it is not giving me any error & not giving the output that I want. Will please someone help me how to get rid of this problem.  For example I have a section  portion like that  **200+ companies| 150m Revenue |  700+ Projects** I first want to load one portion of text then with some delay of 1000ms 2nd portion of the text then with some delay 3rd portion of the text but this code is not working or not giving me any error will please someone help me how to get rid of this problem.